# bypass preloader if images already loaded

Tags: jquery, preloader

I am using [QueryLoader2](https://github.com/Gaya/queryloader2) plugin to preload my images/content before showing my page.

**PROBLEM**
The preloader fires on every page even when that page has been visited (already loaded). It quickly goes to 100% and loads the page. Each time. Every time.

**QUESTION**
How can I adjust the code so that the preloader:
(1) appears if that page hasn't been visited (no cookie)
(2) does not appear at all if the page has been visited (cookie)

**PRELOADER FIRE CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").queryLoader2({
        barColor:"#FFD95F",
        backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,.5)",
        percentage:true,
        barHeight:1,
        minimumTime:500,
        maxTime: 60000,
        onComplete: function(){
            wow.init();
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `deepSearch:false` ?

Comment: Yeah - that had a bad result. Wasn't loading enough images. From what I understand that only has to do with what images load. Doesn't have anything to do with whether or not the preloader appears based off page visit, cookie, cache, etc.